# How do I add a Hyperlink to each item in a column?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

Column B is Employee name and is also an individual Worksheet name.

Anticipated Outcome: A hyperlink to the individual Worksheet on each item in column B.

Issue: The code starts and stops at the top of the list and puts in a hyperlink to the last employee on the list.

```
Sub HyperlinkAdd()
    ts= "Employee List"
    lx = sheets(ts).Range("L1").value
    Sheets(ts).Range("L1").Formula= "=Subtotal(3,B4:B1000)+3"

    For x = 3 to lx
        If Range("B" & x).value <> "" And Range("B" & x).value <> "Employees" Then

           Sheets(ts).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:Selection, Address:="", _
             Subaddress:="'" & Range("B" & x) & "'!A1"

        Else

        End if

    Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: You are using Selection for the anchor which never changes. Use the cell itself - `Range("B" & x)`?

Comment: I could have swore I put that in there a few times, I would not work and I just manually typed it in and it worked perfectly fine. I must have missed something. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub add_hyperlink()

Dim target_range As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set target_range = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))

For Each cell In target_range

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:="https://www.google.com/", SubAddress:= _
        "Sheet1!A1", TextToDisplay:=cell.Value

Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following, simply amend the range you want to work with, I've set it up so it works from B1 to the last populated cell on Column B:

```
Sub HyperlinkAdd()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your working worksheet, amend as required
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column b
Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("B1"), ws.Range("B" & LastRow))
'set the range to work with

For Each cell In rng
  If cell.Value <> "" And cell.Value <> "Employees" Then
    ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cell, Address:="", SubAddress:=cell.Value & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=cell.Value
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I take a different tack and make a table of contents with each sheet (with exceptions) added to the list, and hyperlinks forward and back.  You'll want to change the location of the "return" link on the employee sheet to somewhere suitable.

```
Private Sub Make_TOC()
'TOC Table of contents Hyperlink
Dim bkEmployees As Workbook
Set bkEmployees = ActiveWorkbook
Dim shContents As Worksheet, shDetail As Worksheet

If Not WorksheetExists("Contents") Then
    Set shContents = bkEmployees.Sheets.Add(before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1))
    shContents.Name = "Contents"
Else
    Set shContents = bkEmployees.Sheets("Contents")
    shContents.Move before:=bkEmployees.Sheets(1)
End If

shContents.Activate
shContents.Range("A1").Select
shContents.Columns("A:B").NumberFormat = "@"

For locX = 2 To bkEmployees.Sheets.Count
    Select Case bkEmployees.Sheets(locX).Name

    'add any sheets you don't want messed with
        Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Contents"
            'don't include the sheets above in the TOC
        Case Else
            shContents.Cells(locX, 1) = bkEmployees.Sheets(locX).Name
            shContents.Cells(locX, 1).Select

            strSubAddress = "'" & shContents.Cells(locX, 1).Value & "'!A1"
            shContents.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=shContents.Cells(locX, 1), _
            Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & bkEmployees.Sheets(locX).Name & "'" & "!A1", _
            TextToDisplay:=bkEmployees.Sheets(locX).Name, ScreenTip:="Go to Detail Sheet"

            'change this code to put the anchor for the return link somewhere suitable.
            bkEmployees.Sheets(locX).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=bkEmployees.Sheets(locX).Cells(1, 1), _
            Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & shContents.Name & "'" & "!A" & locX, _
            TextToDisplay:="Return to TOC", ScreenTip:="Return to Table of Contents"
    End Select
Next locX
shContents.Range("A1").Value = "Table Of Contents"
shContents.Range("A1").Select
shContents.Columns("A").AutoFit
End Sub
```